# Using a variable as a column name in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1146

Here I wrote a mysql procedure which select all `text` type field of specified database 'wp'

and I want to **update** every **text** type field row appending **extra string** via **CONCAT** function.

after I **call test2** , error shows:

```
Query : call test2()

Error Code : 1146
Table 'wp._tbl' doesn't exist

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
---------------------------------------------------
```

mysql regards **_tbl** as a string but not a variable.

So can I correct this?

code:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `wp`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test2`$$
CREATE
    PROCEDURE `test2`()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE _tbl VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE _cl VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE notFound INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'wp' AND data_type ='text';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET notFound =1;
    OPEN cur;
        WHILE notFound = 0 DO
            FETCH cur INTO _tbl,_cl;
            UPDATE _tbl SET _cl = CONCAT(_cl,'extra string goes here.....');
            IF NOT noFound THEN SET notFound = 0;
            END IF;
        END WHILE;
    CLOSE cur;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: SQL does not support a variable in that position -- only an identifier. The only way this is possible is with ["dynamic SQL"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471570/dynamic-mysql-with-local-variables), but that starts to get *really messy*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). 
Also see [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)